# How to resolve Error of "has no attribute" in python code when trying to run one CNN related code?

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to run the modified python code related to CNN present into this link: https://github.com/nephashi/GaitRecognitionCNN

and getting the error as:

File "/root/PycharmProjects/CNNCheck/Run_CNN.py", line 60, in 
    model.add(Conv2D121(8, (5, 5), padding='valid'))

File "/root/PycharmProjects/CNNCheck/layers/Conv2D121.py", line 35, in **init**

self.data_format = conv_utils.normalize_data_format(data_format)

AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.conv_utils' has no attribute 'normalize_data_format'

I have created a python Project named as: CNNCheck

that contains a python file named as: Run_CNN.py and one directory named as: layers which contain a file named as: Conv2D121.py and coded as follow:

Run_CNN.py

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from layers.Conv2D121 import Conv2D121


path1="/home/sanjay/CASIA_B90PerfectCentrallyAlinged_Resized_with_140by140_Energy_Image/"
#path1="/home/sanjay/CASIA_B90PerfectCentrallyAlinged_CODEI_OneCycle_frames-20_Resized_with_140by140_Energy_Image/"
all_images = []
all_labels = []
subjects = os.listdir(path1)
numberOfSubject = len(subjects)
print('Number of Subjects: ', numberOfSubject)
for number1 in range(0, numberOfSubject):  # numberOfSubject
    path2 = (path1 + subjects[number1] + '/')
    sequences = os.listdir(path2);
    numberOfsequences = len(sequences)
    for number2 in range(4, numberOfsequences):
        path3 = path2 + sequences[number2]
        img = cv2.imread(path3 , 0)
        img = img.reshape(140, 140, 1)
        all_images.append(img)
        all_labels.append(number1)
x_train = np.array(all_images)
y_train = np.array(all_labels)
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train)


all_images = []
all_labels = []

for number1 in range(0, numberOfSubject):  # numberOfSubject
    path2 = (path1 + subjects[number1] + '/')
    sequences = os.listdir(path2);
    numberOfsequences = len(sequences)
    for number2 in range(0, 4):
        path3 = path2 + sequences[number2]
        img = cv2.imread(path3 , 0)
        img = img.reshape(140, 140, 1)
        all_images.append(img)
        all_labels.append(number1)
x_test = np.array(all_images)
y_test = np.array(all_labels)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test)

batch_size = 4
num_classes = 123
epochs = 10000

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8, (5, 5), padding='valid',
                 input_shape=(140, 140, 1)))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2, padding='valid'))
model.add(Conv2D121(8, (5, 5), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2, padding='valid'))
model.add(Conv2D121(8, (5, 5), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2, padding='valid'))
model.add(Conv2D121(8, (5, 5), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2, padding='valid'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(num_classes, input_shape=(200,)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.summary()
```

Conv2D121.py

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras import initializers
from keras import regularizers
from keras import constraints
from keras.engine.base_layer import Layer
from keras.engine.base_layer import InputSpec
from keras.utils import conv_utils

# 121 means one-to-one connection :)
class Conv2D121(Layer):

    def __init__(self, filters,
                 kernel_size,
                 strides=1,
                 rank=2,
                 padding='valid',
                 data_format=None,
                 use_bias=True,
                 kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                 bias_initializer='zeros',
                 kernel_regularizer=None,
                 bias_regularizer=None,
                 kernel_constraint=None,
                 bias_constraint=None,
                 **kwargs
                 ):
        super(Conv2D121, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rank = rank
        self.filters = filters
        self.kernel_size = conv_utils.normalize_tuple(kernel_size, rank, 'kernel_size')
        self.strides = conv_utils.normalize_tuple(strides, rank, 'strides')
        # normalize_padding: 检查padding的值，只有['valid', 'same', 'causal']三个值合法
        self.padding = conv_utils.normalize_padding(padding)
        # data_format: 检查
        self.data_format = conv_utils.normalize_data_format(data_format)
        self.use_bias = use_bias,
        self.kernel_initializer = initializers.get(kernel_initializer)
        self.bias_initializer = initializers.get(bias_initializer)
        self.kernel_regularizer = regularizers.get(kernel_regularizer)
        self.bias_regularizer = regularizers.get(bias_regularizer)
        self.kernel_constraint = constraints.get(kernel_constraint)
        self.bias_constraint = constraints.get(bias_constraint)
        self.input_spec = InputSpec(ndim=self.rank + 2)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        if self.data_format == 'channels_first':
            channel_axis = 1
        else:
            channel_axis = -1
        if input_shape[channel_axis] is None:
            raise ValueError('The channel dimension of the inputs '
                             'should be defined. Found `None`.')
        input_dim = input_shape[channel_axis]
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        if input_dim != self.filters:
            raise ValueError('Because nature of one-to-one connnection, '
                             'input dimension must be equal to filters number')
        kernel_shape = self.kernel_size + (1, 1)

        self.kernels = []

        for i in range(input_dim):
            self.kernels.append(self.add_weight(
                shape=kernel_shape,
                # initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                name='kernel' + str(i),
                regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
                constraint=self.kernel_constraint
            ))

        if self.use_bias:
            self.bias = self.add_weight(
                shape=(self.input_dim,),
                initializer=self.bias_initializer,
                name='bias',
                regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
                constraint=self.bias_constraint
            )
        else:
            self.bias = None

        self.input_spec = InputSpec(ndim=self.rank + 2,
                                    axes={channel_axis: input_dim})
        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        if self.rank != 2:
            raise ValueError('currently this layer only support 2D data.')

        input_slices = []

        # now we need to slice the input_dim dimension input and do convolution
        for i in range(self.input_dim):
            slice = K.expand_dims(inputs[:, :, :, i], axis=3)
            input_slices.append(slice)

        output_slices = []

        for i in range(self.input_dim):
            slice = K.conv2d(
                input_slices[i],
                self.kernels[i],
                strides=self.strides,
                padding=self.padding,
                data_format=self.data_format,
            )
            output_slices.append(slice)

        output = K.concatenate(output_slices, axis=3)

        if (self.use_bias):
            output = K.bias_add(
                output,
                self.bias,
                data_format=self.data_format
            )

        return output

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        if self.data_format == 'channels_last':
            space = input_shape[1:-1]
            new_space = []
            for i in range(len(space)):
                new_dim = conv_utils.conv_output_length(
                    space[i],
                    self.kernel_size[i],
                    padding=self.padding,
                    stride=self.strides[i])
                new_space.append(new_dim)
            return (input_shape[0],) + tuple(new_space) + (self.filters,)
        if self.data_format == 'channels_first':
            space = input_shape[2:]
            new_space = []
            for i in range(len(space)):
                new_dim = conv_utils.conv_output_length(
                    space[i],
                    self.kernel_size[i],
                    padding=self.padding,
                    stride=self.strides[i])
                new_space.append(new_dim)
            return (input_shape[0], self.filters) + tuple(new_space)
```

How we can resolve the error occur as:

File "/root/PycharmProjects/CNNCheck/Run_CNN.py", line 60, in 
    model.add(Conv2D121(8, (5, 5), padding='valid'))

File "/root/PycharmProjects/CNNCheck/layers/Conv2D121.py", line 35, in **init**

self.data_format = conv_utils.normalize_data_format(data_format)

AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.conv_utils' has no attribute 'normalize_data_format'

Answer (score 1):

there was keras version problem.

I installed keras 2.2.0 insted of keras 2.2.4

so the problem is resolved.